# Aiogram fails to create sticker pack

Tags: aiogram

I ran into a problem with stickers, the code is below

```py
async def sticker_set(msg:types.Message):
    await bot.create_new_sticker_set(
    user_id=msg.from_user.id, 
    name = "what_den_things",
    title = "What Denis thinks",
    png_sticker = "boring.png", 
    emojis = ""
    
    )
```

Comment: Either translate question to English or post it at https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hello everyone, I ran into a problem with stickers, the code is below

Comment: What is your problem? Can you please describe what happens and what should happen

Comment: I want to add a sticker through the bot, but it doesn't work :(